# What is the recommended encoding for caf audio files using AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

If I want to record to a "caf" audio file on iOS, what's the recommended audio encoding?  I think kAudioFormatMPEGLayer2 is right but I can't seem to find a definitive answer using google.  Here's my code if that's helpful.

```
NSString *audioFilePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
_audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];
_audioQuality = [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityHigh];
_audioEncoding = [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEGLayer2];
_audioChannels = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
_audioSampleRate = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        _audioQuality, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
        _audioEncoding, AVFormatIDKey,
        _audioChannels, AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
        _audioSampleRate, AVSampleRateKey,
        nil];

NSError *error = nil;

_audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
              initWithURL:_audioFileURL
              settings:recordSettings
              error:&error];

_audioRecorder.delegate = self;
```

Comment: What does "recommended" mean? Is there a problem when you run your code? If so, what?

Comment: @matt, That's a good question.  I know caf files can be encoded with different encoders but was hoping there was one that most people used and then would just use that one.  I thought I would post this question to see if someone that knows more about audio encoding than me could recommend something.  I don't meant o be vague, I just don't know anything about recording audio.  Sorry.

Comment: Well, what do you want out of this recording? Different formats are obviously good for different goals.

Comment: @matt thanks for helping me out on this.  I'm actually working on a pull-request for this open source audio module for react native: https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio .  I'm adding encoding and the default file type will be 'caf'.  So something in the middle i guess.  I found this old post that says that kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 makes good decent recordings that are small in size (http://blog.totodotnet.net/2009/05/best-audio-format-for-iphone-audio.html).  Maybe that should be the default and the user can always pick a different encoding type if they like.